# Render email messages to PS/PDF?

Tags: email, printing, rfc822

I'm looking for a way to take a standard mail message (RFC 822 et. al) in a text file (say, from a mail spool or maildir), format it nicely, and output a postscript or PDF file suitable for printing. I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel in terms of developing a pleasing layout, and I'm not familiar with PostScript or any graphics libraries anyway.

Are there any ready-made libraries or tools that can produce output similar to what most mail clients send to a printer? I've tried a couple of Linux command-line tools (like mp), but the output isn't very attractive.

Comment: You'll need to specify a programming language (With Java use iText for instance), if you mean command line tools then this question aught to be moved to super-user.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem in two ways:

**First:**

Pass e-mail in ["HTML Tidy"](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) component or the ["HTML Beautifier .Net"](http://htmlbeauty.net/) for the formatting and cleanup, and then convert with the "PDF Metamorphosis .Net"(www.sautinsoft.net).

Your HTML -> filter, clean up, modify HTML -> convert -> Your PDF

**Second way:**

Immediately send a message to "PDF Metamorphosis" for the converting to pdf.

Your HTML -> convert -> Your PDF

For example:

```
SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis p = new SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis();
string inputFile = @"С:\email.html";
string outputFile = @"С:\email.pdf";

int result = p.HtmlToPdfConvertFile(inputFile, outputFile);

if (result == 0)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Converted successfully!");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputFile);
}
```